# Spark - is there a way to see the task progress?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a Spark task that is supposed to output the result DataFrame to MongoDB via the connector.

When I just output the result via show method of the DF, the task runs pretty fast (though depends highly on the number of rows I'm showing). Like 40 seconds per default show().

However, when I just want to count the number of rows using count() method of the DataFrame, it takes forever and never finishes. I'm not even sure whether it's actually doing something. It's just stuck at the stage:

> Building 83% > :run

Same happens when I'm trying to output the result to my local MongoDB. And the collection I'm outputting to stays empty.

I don't really get why this is happening. Either the task takes too long or it's just stuck for some reason.

Is there a way to track whether something is actually happening at that stage?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the Spark UI from your browser?

Comment: No, never tried. How can I do it?

Comment: Found it. Thanks.